# How to show the "View chart" on main UI?

Tags: android

In my Android program, in the main activity (ReadLog), I will call another activity (History) like below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(ReadLog.this, History.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in History activity, I will finish making a View called `chart` and start to show it like below.

```
View chart = ...;
setContentView(chart);
```

But now I hope to show it on main UI. So I add a View on main UI (below some buttons), and hope to show the `chart` inside of the main UI's View. How can I do it?

Comment: what is the problem that you run into with your attempt?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, so the only problem is the method unknown.

Comment: what part is unknown? making the view? you could perhaps just make an empty id'd `LinearLayout` in your main view xml when you're done then use the `linearlayout.addView(chart)`

Comment: Thank you very much! This way works!